# Using Files with headers

Tags: c++, file, class, c++11

I keep getting an error when trying to use ifstream in my header file. They say:

```
FloatList.h:14:15: error: 'ifstream' has not been declared
void getList(ifstream&);
FloatList.cpp:16:6: error: prototype for 'void FloatList::getList(std::ifstream&)'
FloatList.h:14:7: error: candidate is: void FloatList::getList(int&)
void getList(ifstream&);
```

Here is the troubled part in my.h file:

```
public:
    FloatList();                // constructor that sets length to 0.
    ~FloatList();               // destructor
    void getList(ifstream&);    // Member function that gets data from a file 
    void printList() const;     // Member function that prints data from that
                            // file to the screen.

};
#endif
```

Here is my implementation file with the member functions:

```
#include "FloatList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Fill in the entire code for the getList function
// The getList function reads the data values from a data file
// into the values array of the class FloatList
void FloatList::getList(ifstream& file)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        if(file >> values[i])
            length++;
    }
}
```

Does it have to do something with how I used ifstream in my header file?

Comment: Does your header file have any `#include`s?

Comment: No, but I used std::ifstream in my header file and it's all working now, thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you declare `using namespace std` *only* in your .cpp file, you are obligated to prefix the `ifstream` name in your header file by `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't forward-declare templates from std safely, so your own option is to include headers before declaration of your class.. method's prototype requires that:
Ordering of code after preprocessor done inclusion should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
class FloatList
{
public:
    FloatList();                // constructor that sets length to 0.
    ~FloatList();               // destructor
    void getList(std::ifstream&);    // Member function that gets data from a file 
    void printList() const;     // Member function that prints data from that
                            // file to the screen.

};

void FloatList::getList(std::ifstream& file)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        if(file >> values[i])
            length++;
    }
}
```

You can reorder headers in .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "FloatList.h"
```

Therefore usage of FloatList.h would require those headers. Another option for you is to move include directives into your header.